# How can I use DATE() in Doctrine 2 DQL?

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

IN Symfony, when i used the following query with DATE function in the mysql i get a error

```
    SELECT employer.companyName AS employerName, jobs.jobId, jobs.industryId, 
jobs.focusId, jobs.companyName, jobs.employerId, jobs.jobTitle, DATE(jobs.createdDate) AS 
createdDate , DATE(jobs.endDate) AS endDate , jobs.replyTo, jobs.featured , jobs.jobType, 
jobs.status  FROM Acme\\AppsBundle\\Entity\\Jobs jobs , Acme\\AppsBundle\\Entity\\Employer 
employer  WHERE  jobs.employerId = employer.employerId  GROUP BY  jobs.jobId  ORDER BY 
jobs.jobId DESC
```

Why is this and what sort of workaround is there to overcome this situation, in the Database these fields i.e end_date is are stored as mysql type 'date'

```
    [2014-09-17 05:52:42] request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception Doctrine\ORM\Query
\QueryException: "[Syntax Error] line 0, col 138: Error: Expected known function, got 
'DATE'" at /.../Doctrine/ORM/Query/QueryException.php line 52 {"exception":"[object] 
(Doctrine\\ORM\\Query\\QueryException: [Syntax Error] line 0, col 138: Error: Expected known function, got 'DATE' at /var/w.../doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query
/QueryException.php:52, Doctrine\\ORM\\Query\\QueryException: SELECT employer.companyName 
AS employerName, jobs.jobId, jobs.industryId, jobs.focusId, jobs.companyName, jobs.employerId, jobs.jobTitle, DATE(jobs.createdDate) AS createdDate , DATE(jobs.endDate) 
AS endDate , jobs.replyTo, jobs.featured , jobs.jobType, jobs.status  FROM Acme\\AppsBundle
\\Entity\\Jobs jobs , Acme\\AppsBundle\\Entity\\Employer employer  WHERE  jobs.employerId 
= employer.employerId  GROUP BY  jobs.jobId  ORDER BY  jobs.jobId DESC  at /var/w...
/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query/QueryException.php:41)"} []
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`DQL` is only aware of few standard sql functions (`coalesce` for example). To be able to use your custom function you need to register it and tell `doctrine` how to translate it into raw sql. Follow these guides:

[Symfony Doc](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/custom_dql_functions.html)

[Doctrine Doc](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/cookbook/dql-user-defined-functions.html)

And check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25099954/any-way-of-using-sha1-in-dql/25104669#25104669)

Answer (score 24):

In addition to the accepted answer there are a tonne of pre-built custom functions available at https://github.com/beberlei/DoctrineExtensions .

These can be then registered in your config like

```
doctrine:
    orm:
        dql:
            string_functions:
                DATE: DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\Date
```

and can then be used in your DQL (as in your query) like

```
DATE(jobs.endDate) AS endDate
```

Comment: If this didn't work for anyone (if it throws a dql not recognised error), when I put `entity_managers:  default:` in the hierarchy before dql, it works.

Comment: That would depend on your configuration. `doctrine.orm.dql` is short for `doctrine.orm.entity_managers.default.dql`. Did you have entity_managers mentioned elsewhere in your config previously?

Comment: yes `entity_managers` is already below `orm` in my `config.yml`, so I assume that is the reason `doctrine.orm.dql` doesn't work but `doctrine.orm.dql` does. Good to know.

Answer (score 12):

Or if you don't want add a new dependency, you can use code like this:

```
$dateTime = new \DateTime();
$qb
   ->andWhere('jobs.endDate BETWEEN :dateMin AND :dateMax')
   ->setParameters(
       [
            'dateMin' => $dateTime->format('Y-m-d 00:00:00'),
            'dateMax' => $dateTime->format('Y-m-d 23:59:59'),
       ]
    );
```