# doctrine Add_date in native query

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine-native-query

I want to select data from table using native query and DATE_ADD but always I got an errors,

this is my sql request:

```
 $qb = $this->_em->createNativeQuery("select  Coalesce (sum(p.nb_sms*p.nb_destination),0)  as multiplesms , sum(p.nb_fax) as nbFax, sum(p.nb_Mail) as nbMail FROM push p WHERE p.id_user=$id and DATE_ADD(p.date_send,7,'DAY') > CURRENT_DATE() and p.statut>0 order by p.date_send  Desc", $rsm);
```

I got an error

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '7,'DAY') > CURRENT_DATE() and p.statut>0 order by p.date_send Desc' at line 1
```

any idea please

Comment: check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/25883677/2393077

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I use DATE() in Doctrine 2 DQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25883616/how-can-i-use-date-in-doctrine-2-dql)

Comment: did you register both ``date_add`` and ``current_date`` functions?

Comment: `orm:
           dql:
              datetime_functions:
                             date: DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\Date
                             date_format: DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\DateFormat
                             dateadd: DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\DateAdd`

Comment: it is not DQL, it is native query SQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

mistake in `DATE_ADD` function syntax
change `DATE_ADD(p.date_send,7,'DAY')` to `DATE_ADD(p.date_send, INTERVAL 7 DAY)`