# Use QueryBuilder with a function ADDTIME() - Symfony2

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I'm trying to use specific mysql function to add a duration (minutes) to a dateTime with a QueryBuilder of Doctrine.

I found DQL function [DATE_ADD](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#dql-functions) but it's only used for `DAY`, `MONTH`

```
$qb = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder();

$qb->select('meeting');
$qb->from('AppBundle:Meeting', 'm');
   ->where('m.timeBegin < :timeEndNext')

   // Error here
   ->andWhere('ADDTIME(m.timeBegin, SEC_TO_TIME(m.duration * 60)) > :timeBeginNext')
   ->setParameters([
         'timeBeginNext' => $timeBeginNext,
         'timeEndNext' => $timeEndNext,
   ]);
```

Comment: did you check out https://github.com/beberlei/DoctrineExtensions

Comment: check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/25883677/2393077