# Retreive date from MySQL DATETIME in Doctrine QueryBuilder

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine

I have a MySQL date stored in **DATETIME** format. So I would like to know how to use `date()` in my Doctrine QueryBuilder's `where` clause. For example, `2013-02-01 12:51:17` is the date in MySQL. But I need to retrieve only the date. This is what I have tried:

```
$qb = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder()
    ->select('t.balance','a.id','t.date')
    ->from('TestMainBundle:Transaction','t')               
    ->groupBy('a.id')
    ->orderBy('a.id')
    ->where("t.date in date('t.date') "); 

return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
```

I received the following error:

> QueryException: [Syntax Error]: Error: Expected Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer::T_OPEN_PARENTHESIS, got 'date'

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25883616/how-can-i-use-date-in-doctrine-2-dql

Answer (score 1):

Hi You can use **SUBSTRING** to fix your probleme

```
->where('SUBSTRING(t.date, 1, 10) IN (:param)')
->setParameter('param', array('2017-04-06'))
```

Answer (score 1):

As it is pointed out in the comments, you cannot use mysql-specific `date()` or `date_format()` functions in Doctrine.

But for the particular case of searching a certain date in the datetime field, you can treat a date like a string, and thus use `LIKE` operator

```
->Where('t.date LIKE :date')
->setParameter(':date', "$date%")
```

As of

> But I need to retreive only the date

you just format the returned value using `format("Y-m-d")` method. i.e.

```
echo $row->getDate()->format("Y-m-d");
```

Answer (score -1):

You don't need the "date" in your where clause.

Juste remove it like this :

```
->where('t.date in (:yourwanteddate)')
->setParameter('yourwanteddate', '2013-02-01 12:51:17');
```

Comment: There is a subtle (but often significant) difference between date and datetime.

Comment: But I need to retreive the query based on date from datetime.In mysql it is in datetime format..i need to retreive the date from this date time.For example:->andWhere(date('t.date') in (:yourwanteddate)')      
->setParameter('yourwanteddate', '2013-02-01');