# How to compare date and datetime with doctrine

Tags: mysql, symfony, datetime, doctrine, symfony-2.3

I need to get all Ad instances where their dates are equals to a specific date. Problem is that the `ad.date` field is a datetime so how do I compare two dates?

I have tried this:

```
$result = $query_builder
            ->select("ad")
            ->where("DATE(ad.date) = :date")
            ->setParameter("date", $some_date)
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult();
```

But a exception was threw:

```
[Syntax Error] line 0, col 50: Error: Expected known function, got 'DATE'
```

I have also thought to create a virtual property but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

In your case doctrine compains that "DATE()" is unknown function. You need to tell to Doctrine that this function is OK. This question was discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25883616/how-can-i-use-date-in-doctrine-2-dql).

Basically you need to use [DoctrineExtensions](https://github.com/beberlei/DoctrineExtensions).
To install it use command:

```
composer require beberlei/DoctrineExtensions
```

And then add to your config.yml:

```
doctrine:
    orm:
        dql:
            string_functions:
                DATE: DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\Date
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compare only the day, or only the the month, or ... you can add this in your config.yml file :

```
orm:
    auto_generate_proxy_classes: '%kernel.debug%'
    naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
    auto_mapping: true
    dql:
        datetime_functions:
            DAY: DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\Day
            MONTH: DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\Month
            YEAR: DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\Year
            DATE: DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\Date
            HOUR: DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\Hour
            MINUTE: DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\Minute
            SECOND: DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\Second
```

then you can use it like that :

```
->where('YEAR(associationname.thedatefield) > YEAR(:anotherdate)')
```

[beberlei/DoctrineExtensions](https://github.com/beberlei/DoctrineExtensions)